# Is there a convenient way to get part of a string from one index to another in C#?

Tags: c#

Is there a way to retrieve the part of a string between two indexes in C#? For example given this string,

```
Hello, world!
```

is there a convenient method to which I can pass "7" and "11" (the indexes of "w" and "d") and get "world"?

Note that I am aware of the `String.Substring()` method, and I know that I can do the following:

```
string s = "Hello, world!";
s.Substring(7, 11 - 7 + 1); // => "world"
```

I also realize that it would be trivial to create an extension method such as the following:

```
public static class Extensions {
    public static string SubstringByIndexes(this string str, int start, int end) {
        return str.Substring(start, end - start + 1);
    }
}
```

However, I just wanted to make sure that there is no built-in way before I start lugging this method around in whatever projects I am working on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [ranges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges), these were added in C# 8.
Note the latter index is 12, not 11, in order to produce "world".

```
string s = "Hello, world!";
string world = s[7..12];
```